# How to search for tagged_places in all friends on Facebook Graph

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am writing an Android app and would like to get the `tagged_places` of all friends of the user. (All friends = all friends who have also installed and authorized my app, because of Facebook permissions.)

My app asks for the following permissions: `user_friends`, `user_tagged_places`

I think it should be a nested query like this:

```
/me?fields=friends{tagged_places}    // query 1
```

But if I run that in my app it results in the following error:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#100) Unknown fields: tagged_places.}}
```

I can run the following queries without error:

```
/me?fields=friends{photos}
/me?fields=friends{albums}
/me?fields=friends{about}
/me?fields=friends{devices}
/me?fields=friends{location}
```

Why do these queries run without error, but just query 1 gives a problem?

Comment: The user_tagged_places permission gives you access to places you're tagged in, not your friends. "tagged_places" is not a valid field of "friends", so query 1 is incorrect. You can get your own tagged places by querying /me?fields=tagged_places.

Comment: Hi subeeshb, thank you for your comment. However I do not agree with the statement that `user_tagged_places` only gives you access to your own `tagged_places`, because I can query the `tagged_places` for each friend individually with the query `/{user-id}/tagged_places`.

Also the documentation states that `/me/friends` returns an array of User objects, and a User Object has a `tagged_places` field.
[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/friends)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug. Facebook fixed it now: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/851547311618854